# Performing 2 DB2 merges base on php parameters, using ID

Tags: php, sql, merge, db2, primary-key

I have a successful select query, where I'm looping and building a row for getting parameters which works correctly

```
while ($row = $orderDetailCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $params = [
            ":INVOICE_NUMBER" => $row["INVOICE_NUMBER"],
            ":CUSTNM" => $row["CUSTNM"],
            ":SELLINGN" => $row["SELLINGN"],
            ":GROUP" => $row["GROUP"],
            ":DTL12" => $row["DTL12"],
            ":DTL13" => $row["DTL13"],
            ":QUANTITY" => $row["QUANTITY"],
            ":COUNT_PLMN_1" => $row["COUNT_PLMN_1"],
            ":LAST_DATE" => $row["LAST_DATE"],
        ];

}
```

My issue now is that, for each row, I need to perform two merges because the data from that select is going to be split into two tables in db2. Some values are truly split between the tables but some values are shared between the two. I'm not sure the best way to perform these two merges because if the first one (products table) inserts, then it creates an ID that I need as a foreign key basically, to insert into the orders table. So on insert I need to grab that newly created ID and use it for `product_id` in the second merge. If the first merge performs the update when matched, then I need to grab the existing ID for that record so that I can update the proper record in the orders table.

My two merge statements:

```
/*products table*/
MERGE INTO products AS P
    USING(VALUES(

        :GROUP,
        :DTL12,
        :DTL13,
        :CUSTNM,
        :SELLINGN,
        :COUNT_PLMN_1,
        :LAST_DATE

        )
    )

AS S(GROUP,DTL12,DTL13,CUSTNM,SELLINGN,COUNT_PLMN_1,LAST_DATE)
ON s.GROUP = p.GROUP and s.DTL12 = p.DTL12 and s.DTL13 = p.DTL13 and s.CUSTNM = p.CUSTNM 

WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET LAST_DATE = s.LAST_DATE

WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT VALUES (s.GROUP,s.DTL12,s.DTL13,s.CUSTNM,s.SELLINGN,s.COUNT_PLMN_1,s.LAST_DATE)



/*ORDERS Table*/
MERGE INTO ORDERS AS PO
    USING(VALUES(

        /*need foreign key, which is id from products table*/
        :QUANTITY,
        :LAST_DATE,
        :INVOICE_NUMBER
    ))

AS S(PRODUCT_ID,quantity_ordered,LAST_DATE,invoice_number)
ON s.PRODUCT_ID = po.id

WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET LAST_DATE = s.LAST_DATE, quantity_ordered = s.quantity_ordered, invoice_number = s.invoice_number

WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT VALUES (s.PRODUCT_ID, s.quantity_ordered, s.LAST_DATE, s.invoice_number)
```

Examples:

If my ROW Returns

```
INVOICE  |  CUSTNM  |  SELLINGNUM  |  GROUP  |  DTL12  |  DTL13  |  QUANTITY  |  COUNT_PLMN_1  |  LAST_DATE
==================================================================================================================
1122        123         321         995        1452       12        13              5               '2018-12-14'
```

Then my insert into products would be

```
products

    ID      |  GROUP  |  DTL12  |  DTL13  |  CUSTNM  |  SELLINGNUM  |  COUNT_PLMN_1  |  LAST_DATE
==========================================================================================================
1                995        1452       12       123         321             5               '2018-12-14'
```

and my insert to orders:

```
ORDERS

PRODUCT_ID  |  QUANTITY_ORDERED  |  LAST_DATE   |  INVOICE
============================================================
1                       13           '2018-12-14'    1122
```

But if my next record matched on my unique qualities with a new invoice, quantity and date

ROW Returns

```
INVOICE  |  CUSTNM  |  SELLINGNUM  |  GROUP  |  DTL12  |  DTL13  |  QUANTITY  |  COUNT_PLMN_1  |  LAST_DATE
==================================================================================================================
1133        123         321           995        1452       12        4              5               '2018-12-18'
```

Then I would update products like so:

```
products

    ID      |  GROUP  |  DTL12  |  DTL13  |  CUSTNM  |  SELLINGNUM  |  COUNT_PLMN_1  |  LAST_DATE
==========================================================================================================
1                995        1452       12       123         321             5               '2018-12-18'
```

and update orders like so:

```
ORDERS

PRODUCT_ID  |  QUANTITY_ORDERED  |  LAST_DATE   |  INVOICE
============================================================
1                       4            '2018-12-18'    1133
```

I guess the main question is: How can I get the ID of a record from the products table (whether it's an existing match OR newly created in the merge) and once I get it, how can I use it for the 2nd merge?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_PRODUCT 
(
  PID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, PKEY INT NOT NULL
, LAST_DATE DATE
) IN USERSPACE1;

CREATE TABLE TEST_ORDER
(
  OID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
, PID INT NOT NULL
, QUANTITY INT
, LAST_DATE DATE
, CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FK FOREIGN KEY (PID) REFERENCES TEST_PRODUCT(PID)
) IN USERSPACE1;

WITH 
-- Just an emulation of the row of input parameters
-- PKEY is for PRODUCT, LAST_DATE for both, QUANTITY - for ORDER
  ROW (PKEY, LAST_DATE, QUANTITY) AS (VALUES (1, CURRENT DATE, 20))

-- Processing PRODUCT  
-- UPDATE if such PKEY as in ROW exists in PRODUCT
, PU AS 
(
  SELECT PID 
  FROM NEW TABLE
  (
  UPDATE TEST_PRODUCT
  SET (LAST_DATE) = (SELECT LAST_DATE FROM ROW)
  WHERE PKEY = (SELECT PKEY FROM ROW)
  )
)
-- INSERT previous UPDATE didn't updated any row
, PI AS
(
  SELECT PID
  FROM NEW TABLE
  (
  INSERT INTO TEST_PRODUCT (PKEY, LAST_DATE) 
  SELECT PKEY, CAST(NULL AS DATE) 
  FROM ROW
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM PU)
  )
)
-- PID of PRODUCT inserted / updated by either previous INSERT or UPDATE
-- It must be exactly 1 row
, PID AS
(
SELECT COALESCE(PU.PID, PI.PID) AS PID
FROM PU
FULL OUTER JOIN PI ON 0=0
)

-- Processing ORDER
-- Both UPDATE and INSERT below use PRODUCT id (PID) affected earlier
-- UPDATE if such PID from the previous SELECT exists in ORDER
, OU AS 
(
  SELECT OID, PID, QUANTITY
  FROM NEW TABLE
  (
  UPDATE TEST_ORDER
  SET (LAST_DATE, QUANTITY) = (SELECT LAST_DATE, QUANTITY FROM ROW)
  WHERE PID = (SELECT PID FROM PID)
  )
)
-- INSERT previous UPDATE didn't updated any row
, OI AS
(
  SELECT OID, PID, QUANTITY
  FROM NEW TABLE
  (
  INSERT INTO TEST_ORDER (PID, LAST_DATE, QUANTITY) 
  SELECT PID.PID, ROW.LAST_DATE, ROW.QUANTITY
  FROM ROW, PID
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM OU)
  )
)
-- Final select
-- We must use it event if we don't need it :)
-- Here is output of ORDER row affected (updated or inserted)
SELECT 
  COALESCE(OU.OID, OI.OID) OID
, COALESCE(OU.PID, OI.PID) PID 
, COALESCE(OU.QUANTITY, OI.QUANTITY) QUANTITY
FROM OU FULL OUTER JOIN OI ON 0=0;
```

Quite a long statement, demonstrating the technique about how to "split" an input row to update/insert into 2 tables with parent / child relationship. We can do this with a single statement (in Db2 for LUW at least). See the [Retrieval of result sets from an SQL data change statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/c0011133.html).
You may run the last statement as is changing the `ROW` constants only and see, what happens with `PRODUCT` and `ORDER` after each such a run.